# Gerrit Mail Error Server smtp.xxx.net rejected from address gerrit2@ubuntu

Tags: smtp, gerrit

In my gerrit_config file, I'm specifying an email address builduser@mycompany.com for SMTP.  However, when gerrit tries to send the confirmation email to a new user from the WebUI, the log show that the user gerrit2@ubuntu is bouncing off the smtp server!  What gives?  gerrit2 is only the linux user that installed and hosts the gerrit repos?

In other words, Gerrit seems to be completely ignoring the smtpUser settings in sendemail section.

Thanks!
AJ

Comment: How do you configure that `From:` address? Via sendemail.from? See https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#sendemail.from

Comment: The default for sendemail.from is MIXED.  I'm not sure why that would make Gerrit completely ignore the smtpUser setting.

Comment: That seemed to work.  I set it up as from = (Code Review) <user@mail.com> and that did the trick.  I wish the documentation was more specific around this.  Thanks StephenKing.

Comment: Don't mix up SMTP auth credentials with the `From:` header. The one is that the SMTP server allows to send mails (for domains for what the mail server does not feel responsible), the other one is really the address that the recipient would see. And some mail servers check for that to be an address of the authenticated user, but mostly you can just send mails with arbitrary sender addresses.